# Type com.reactnativecommunity.asyncstorage.AsyncLocalStorageUtil is defined multiple times

Tags: react-native, jitsi-meet

Hello guys I want to use `react-native-jitsi-meet` in my mobile project
and I use `react-native-jitsi-meet` "^2.2.0" version, "react-native":
"0.66.2" version and `"@react-native-async-storage/async-storage": "github:react-native-async-storage/async-storage"` package,
In my `android/app/build.gradle` I exclude `async-storage` but I still get
this error, Is there anyone can understand what is the problem.

> **com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveMergerException: Error while merging dex archives:
> Type com.reactnativecommunity.asyncstorage.AsyncLocalStorageUtil is defined
> multiple times**

```
> implementation(project(':react-native-jitsi-meet')) {
>             exclude group: 'com.facebook',module:'hermes'
>             exclude group: 'com.facebook.react',module:'@react-native-async-storage/async-storage'
>             exclude group: 'com.facebook.react',module:'react-native-svg'
>             exclude group: 'com.facebook.react',module:'react-native-linear-gradient'
>             exclude group: 'com.facebook.react',module:'react-native-vector-icons'
>             transitive = true
>         }
```

Comment: that's tell you define async-storage multiple time , check your code and see where you define again

Comment: I checked but when I erase that exclude line for async-storage it gave me same error

Comment: after that . delete android/app/build folder and clean project and build again

Answer (score 10):

The issue with my project was that the dependency `"@react-native-community"` already has a sub directory of async-storage. If you are using both `@react-native-async-storage`, and `@react-native-community`, it wont be able to build.

Remove either `@react-native-community` or `@react-native-async-storage`. Preferably remove `@react-native-community/async-storage` because the [docs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@react-native-community/async-storage) state that *"Async Storage has moved to new organization: [https://github.com/react-native-async-storage/async-storage"](https://github.com/react-native-async-storage/async-storage%22)*

Then `run npm install.`

Comment: To be clear, `@react-native-async-storage/async-storage` is the package to keep.